# Why does my url for my website have a ?. Already changed .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

I am using ExpressionEngine as a CMS for my site.  I've created an .htaccess with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.gsmastersinc.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://gsmastersinc.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Why do all of my urls for my site have a ? in them?  Ex.   myurl/?/contact.

You can see what I'm talking about here: http://gsmastersinc.com, then click on any nav link.  When hovering, it does not show the ?, only after clicking it.

I have to have the ? after the /index.php on the 13th line or the link is broken and I get a 404.

I've been searching for an answer all morning, but everything that comes up has to do with .NET or something similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change order of your rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.gsmastersinc.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://gsmastersinc.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

**In general keep your 301 rules before internal rewrite rules.**

Comment: Man, i'm not sure what's different other than the order, but your solution worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes due to 301 rule appearing at bottom it is redirecting intenally rewritten URL.